# Delphi, retrieve both visible text and hidden hyperlink when pasting into a delphi application

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, clipboard

How can I do that? I've been looking all over the internet to find some clues but failed.
You can click on a link in the browser and copy it and then paste it into a word doc document for example. 
I using a tcxGrid with some fields and want to paste this link into the field. The field will show you the text but if you click on it it will open the browser with this link. 
I can fix all the later part but I don't know how to extract the text and the link from the clipboard.
Does anyone know how to do it?

I've found an old article that describes how you can do it but the result is not good. I get Chinese text instead of HTML.. see below my test code:

```
function TForm2.clipBoardAsHTML: string;
var
  CF_HTML: UINT;
  CFSTR_INETURL: UINT;
  URL: THandle;
  HTML: THandle;
  Ptr: PChar;
begin
  CF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
  CFSTR_INETURL := RegisterClipboardFormat('UniformResourceLocator');
  result := '';
  with Clipboard do
  begin
    Open;
    try
      HTML := GetAsHandle(CF_HTML);
      if HTML <> 0 then
      begin
        Ptr := PChar(GlobalLock(HTML));
        if Ptr <> nil then
        try
          Result := Ptr;
        finally
          GlobalUnlock(HTML);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Data looks like:
敖獲潩㩮⸱ര匊慴瑲呈䱍〺〰〰〰ㄲര䔊摮呈䱍〺〰〰㈰㐳ള匊慴
 and much more.

So something is wrong with my code it looks.. :(

The recommended format CFSTR_INETURL does not exist in the clipboard when takes a copy from Firefox, and Excel so I couldn't get any data using that format.

==================================

Latest test - Retrieve of format names.

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  s: string;
  szFmtBuf: array[0..350] of PWideChar;
  fn: string;
  fmt: integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  for i := 0 to clipBoard.FormatCount - 1 do
  begin
    fmt := clipBoard.Formats[i];
    getClipBoardFormatName(fmt,@szFmtBuf,sizeOf(szFmtBuf));
    fn := WideCharToString(@szFmtBuf);
    if fmt >= 49152 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(fmt.ToString+ ' - '+fn);
  end;
end;
```

Finally I made this code work :) but the main question how I'll get the url from the clipboard are still unsolved. :(
If I loop through all found formats I only get garbage from them.
The formats from Firefox looks:

```
49161 - DataObject
49451 - text/html
49348 - HTML Format
50225 - text/_moz_htmlcontext
50223 - text/_moz_htmlinfo
50222 - text/x-moz-url-priv
49171 - Ole Private Data
```

Comment: Inspect which formats are in the clipboard. Do test with a large range of browsers.

Comment: "*I get Chinese text instead of HTML*" - that is commonly known as "Mojibake", which happens when you interpret 8bit (ANSI/UTF-8) text as if it were 16bit (UCS-2/UTF-16). Remember that `PChar` is `PWideChar` in D2009+, but `CF_HTML` uses a mix of ASCII and UTF-8, so you need to use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PWideChar`.

Comment: Also, `'URL Format'` is the wrong name to use for `CFSTR_INETURL`. the correct name is `'UniformResourceLocator'` instead

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on which format(s) the copier decides to place on the clipboard. It may place multiple formats on the clipboard at a time.

A hyperlink with url and optional text may be represented using either:

- the Shell [`CFSTR_INETURL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/clipboard) format (registered name: `'UniformResourceLocator'`) containing the URL of the link, and the [`CF_(UNICODE)TEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) format containing the text of the link, if any.
- the [`CF_HTML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format) format (registered name: `'HTML Format'`) containing whole fragments of HTML, including `<a>` hyperlinks and optional display text.

The VCL's [`TClipboard`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard) class has [`HasFormat()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard.HasFormat) and [`GetAsHandle()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard.GetAsHandle) methods for accessing the data of formats other than `CF_(UNICODE)TEXT` (which can be retrieved using the [`TClipboard.AsText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard.AsText) property).

You need to use the Win32 [`RegisterClipboardFormat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclipboardformatw) function at runtime to get the format IDs for `CFSTR_INETURL` and `CF_HTML` (using the name strings mentioned above) before you can then use those IDs with `HasFormat()` and `GetAsHandle()`.

You can also enumerate the formats that are currently available on the clipboard, using the [`TClipboard.FormatCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard.FormatCount) and [`TClipboard.Formats[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard.Formats) properties. For format IDs in the `$C000..$FFFF` range, use the Win32 [`GetClipboardFormatName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardformatnamew) function to retrieve the names that were originally registered with `RegisterClipboardFormat()`.

Comment: I've tried to find CFSTR_INETURL and CF_HTML in delphi(I'm using XE6) but no. I also looked in MS-documentation but can't find the value of those.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question a few hours ago but something came in between and I forgot to save my edits but now they are in place.  I think I did what you recommended except for the registration of CFSTR_INETURL. But I have tested 'UniformResourceLocator' now but firefox doesn't seem to use that format.

Comment: @larand then you are just going to have to enumerate the available formats on the clipboard to see what Firefox actually offers.